# Passing parameter to a windows service in c#

Tags: c#

I am creating a windows service which has to run on specific days and time. I am passing these variables using an XML document. Here is my code for passing the values

```
   static void Main()
    {
        ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;

        Service1= new Service1();          

        //Load setting from xml and assign to variables "daysToExec" and "timeToExec"
        LoadSettings();
        Service1.daysToExecute = daysToExec;
        Service1.timeToExecute = timeToExec;
        ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] { Service1 };
        ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);          

    }
```

The code for OnStart() in Service1.cs

```
    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
     timer1.Enable = true;
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (string DayToRun in daysToExecute)
        {
            if (DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek.ToString().ToUpper().Equals(DayToRun.ToUpper())  && DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString().Equals(timeToExecute)) 
            {
                Process.Start("Path to executable");
            }
        }
    }
```

But this is not starting the executable. Is there something wrong with this code.

Thanks.

Comment: Just asking the obvious here... are there strings in daysToExecute when it hits the Timer1_Tick call?

Also, are you sure the timeToExec is matching with your format?

Comment: Yes. daysToExec is list of strings. I dont know if it has any values. It would be helpful if you can tell me how to see that.

Thanks for your reply.

Comment: you should use some logging funciton to write out to a text file at a minimum.  Then in main you can write out information about your parameters.  (There are ways to debug the service, but writing to a text file is probably simplest for this case)

Comment: also, with this setup you are going to execute at all the times you specify on all the days you specify.  Also, what is the value for your timer to tick?  if it is more than a minute then you could miss your times.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will log the values see if it getting.I set the timer interval to 3 seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer atlast. I was using System.Windows.Forms.Timer and for some reason it was not at all executing the timer_tick method. After using System.Timers.Timer it worked fine.

Thanks for your comments.

Comment: The Windows Forms Timer is built on window messages, so you need a message pump (created by Application.Run) for it to work. SOmething you typically don't have in a service application.

BTW, are you reinventing the Windows Task Scheduler?

Comment: Yes.. I guess. That's what the requirement is. Dont like it but have to do it.